# What technology(ies) and language(s) is Microsoft Navison implemented with/in?

Tags: navision

Navision is also known as Microsoft Dynamics NAV.

Comment: You have accepted a wrong answer!!! The business logic in Dynamics NAV is not written in X++ !!! and Oracle is not supported by Dynamics NAV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navision's application logic is written using a proprietary language called C/AL, which is loosely based on Pascal.  It currently offers both a native database option as well as MS SQL Server.

The next version (NAV 2009) will use .NET assemblies served via IIS.  C/AL logic will be translated to C# code and deployed to the server.

Answer (score 1):

NAV 2009 is indeed using generated .Net assemblies, but it is WCF based. It is not required to use IIS. NAV 2009 does not support interfaces into their server code apart from the (web) services.

NAV 2009 includes both the new Role-Tailored Client, which uses the Service Tier and the old Classic Client, which directly accesses the NAV Database Server.